# Map values in Collectors.groupingBy()

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

For the sake of this example, let's assume I have a simple type `Tuple` with two attributes:

```
interface Tuple<T, U> {
    T getFirst();
    U getSecond();
}
```

Now I want to transform a collection of `(first, second)` tuples into a map which maps each `first` value to a set of all `second` values contained in tuples with that specific `first` value. The method `groupSecondByFirst()` shows a possible implementation doing what I want:

```
<T, U> Map<T, Set<U>> groupSecondByFirst(Set<Tuple<T, U>> tuples) {
    Map<T, Set<U>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Tuple<T, U> i : tuples) {
        result.computeIfAbsent(i.getFirst(), x -> new HashSet<>()).add(i.getSecond());
    }

    return result;
}
```

If the input was `[(1, "one"), (1, "eins"), (1, "uno"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")]` the output would be `{ 1 = ["one", "eins", "uno"], 2 = ["two"], 3 = ["three"] }`

I would like to know whether and how I can implement this using the streams framework. The best I got is the following expression, which returns a map which contains the full tuple as values and not just their `second` elements:

```
Map<T, Set<Tuple<T, U>>> collect = tuples.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Tuple::getFirst, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I found a solution; It involves `Collections.mapping()`, which can wrap a collector and apply mapping function over stream to supply elements to the wrapped collector:

```
static <T, U> Map<T, Set<U>> groupSecondByFirst(Collection<Tuple<T, U>> tuples) {
    return tuples
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                Tuple::getFirst,
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Tuple::getSecond,
                    Collectors.toSet())));
}
```